# Create ShuffledRDD with KeyOrdering and Aggregator

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to work around the INDETERMINATE state with RDDs related to this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-23243

The issue is I have a couple repartitions in the pipeline, and the repartitions cause the RDD to go from DETERMINISTIC to UNORDERED to INDETERMINATE.  Any operation on an INDETERMINATE RDD can't be retried, so the job is prone to failure if an issue happens with an executor on stages in those states.

I've read through the RDD code where deterministic state is computed:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1952-L1972

Based on that logic, if I could make a `ShuffledRDD` with an `OrderingKey` and an `Aggregator`, then the DAG would interpret the RDD as DETERMINISTIC, and not care about the upstream partition that caused partitions to become unordered.

The flow has `groupByKey` operations using a `Long` key between the repartitions, which could produce ShuffledRDDs with an aggregator (accumulate to buffer) and a key ordering, but that doesn't seem to happen.  If I use `groupByKey`, then I get a `ShuffleRDD` with an `Aggregator`. If I use `sortWithinPartitions` then I get a `ShuffleRDD` with a `KeyOrdering`.  If I sort then groupByKey, I get a `MapPartitionsRDD` (that happens to be sorted by the key) wrapped around the `ShuffleRDD`.

`ShuffleRDD` is a DeveloperAPI class, so I don't know if it's safe to construct one directly and give it the ordering and grouping instances.  This sort of chain happens in a few places too, so I'm not very keen on changing groupByKey into deterministicGroupByKey everywhere, just to get the deterministic behavior.

I'm looking for anyone who can recommend a good way to regain determinism on an RDD after it has gone through a repartition.

**Update**

Checkpointing "works" in that the RDD becomes deterministic, but comes at the expense of added load on replicated storage.  An RDD with a deterministic partitioner and fully sorted records is deterministic, even if the logic doesn't recognize that.  The code that computes the determinism level acknowledges this by checking for the existence of an OrderingKey and Aggregator on a ShuffledRDD.  My trouble is I can't find any way to create one of those using the public APIs. Neither PairRDDFunctions nor OrderedRddFunctions seem to have a method to do this.

Comment: RDDs are legacy, so when I look at your first link, may be you should not worry so much.

Comment: did u resolve btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link https://medium.com/@viirya/unstable-als-fitting-caused-by-indeterminate-rdd-output-48bcd3bf29eb  gives you guidance.

> Summarizing: ... To fix this issue, we need to make input RDD to ALS
>   fitting as deterministic. **The very simple way to do that is to
>   checkpoint the RDD.** Because checkpoint saves the RDD into reliable
>   storage like HDFS, rerun of the checkpointed RDD just reads needed
>   partitions back from disk. ...

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that checkpointing is detrimental in my case because it produces very many small files in HDFS, and leads to an overwhelmed namenode.

Comment: Well I am not sure that is relevant as you can repartition.